# nginx if specific subdomain endpoint

Tags: nginx

I'd like to put robots.txt for the subdomain `dev.` to point to a specific robots.txt static file.

What routing rule do I need?

This is what i'm thinking:

```
if ($host = "dev.example.com") {
    location ^~ /robots.txt {
       allow all;
       root  /static/disallow/robots.txt;
    }
}
```

Based on [Nginx subdomain configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905378/nginx-subdomain-configuration) I believe I may need to just make separate server blocks and use `include`'s. If not a simple routing rule, is the includes method how this is typically done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting a specific robots.txt for each subdomain, you can do so with separate server blocks like this, which you allude (and link) to in your question:

```
server {
    server_name subdomainA.domain.com;
    include /common/config/path;
    location = /robots.txt {
        root /subdomainA/path;
    }
}
server {
    server_name subdomainB.domain.com;
    include /common/config/path;
    location = /robots.txt {
        root /subdomainB/path;
    }
}
```

Regarding your other approach, have you read [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)?